# Efficient conversion between two partition representations

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I have a `list` of distinct expressions.  We can represent a partitioning of `list` in two ways:

1. As a list of sublists `partitions = {{a, b, ...}, {x, y, ...}, ...}`.
2. As a `vector` of integer partition indices, corresponding to each element of `list`.

Example:

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e}
partitions = {{a,e}, {}, {c,d,b}}
vector = {1, 3, 3, 3, 1}
```

Here `{a,e}` has index `1`, `{}` has index `2` and `{c,d,b}` has index `3`.

---

What is the fastest way to convert from the `partitions` representation to the `vector` representation?

`list` may contain any expression, including lists. The conversion must be as fast as possible, with special attention given to the situation where `list` contains only integers.

A possible implementation is

```
partitionToVector[list_, partitions_] := 
    list /. Dispatch[Join @@ Thread /@ Thread[partitions -> Range@Length[partitions]]]
```

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Take the partitions in consecutive order and number them starting with 1.  Thus `{a,e}` receives the index 1.  Then both `a` and `e` will be replaced with 1 in `list`.  Another way to put it: There's a direct correspondence between elements of `list` and `vector` (that are in the same position).  The number in `vector` indicates which partition the corresponding element of `list` belongs to.

Comment: @Sjoerd I mean that `list` is given.  Then `vector` and `partitions` are two different but equivalent representations for a partitioning of `list`. I want to state the problem better, but I don't really understand why you find it misleading.  BTW this is for use with community detection algorithms and igraph. igraph likes the `vector` representation and Mathematica likes the `partitions` representation.

Comment: Do you guarantee that `list` contains no duplicates?  Do you guarantee that every element of `list` appears exactly once in `partitions`?

Comment: @EricTowers Yes, that's why I said "I have a list of *distinct* expressions."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This seems to be about twice faster on large generic lists, and I made it somewhat faster still on integer lists (about 4-5x faster, per my tests):

```
ClearAll[partitionToVectorLS];
partitionToVectorLS[list : {__Integer}, partitions_, sparsenessThreshold_: 10] :=
  Module[{max = Max[list], min = Min[list], copy = partitions, 
      sparseness, inds, nonsparseQ, dim
    },
    dim = max - min + 1;
    sparseness = dim/Length[list];
    nonsparseQ = sparseness < sparsenessThreshold;
    inds = If[TrueQ @ nonsparseQ, Range[dim], SparseArray[{}, dim]];
    copy[[All, All]] = Range[Length[partitions]];
    inds[[Join @@ partitions - min + 1]] = Join @@ copy;
    If[nonsparseQ, Identity, Normal]@inds[[list - min + 1]]
  ];


partitionToVectorLS[list_, partitions_] :=
  Module[{copy = partitions},
    copy[[All, All]] = Range[Length[partitions]];
    Lookup[AssociationThread[Flatten[partitions,1], Flatten[copy,1]], list]
  ]
```

Note that the specialized definition for integers avoids unpacking of inner lists in `partitions`. I have also introduced a sparseness threshold, above which using `inds` list as a faster hash-table with integer keys becomes too memory-consuming, and then we switch to using `SparseArray`.

Comment: The `copy[[All, All]]` trick is cool!

Comment: @Szabolcs I discovered it just now - I just tried and it worked :)

Comment: It's totally confusing how that works: `copy[[All, All]] == copy` evaluates to `True`, and obviously, `copy = Range[Length[partitions]]` sets `copy` to `{1, 2, 3}`. So why does it work?

Comment: @march Well, if I have a 2-level list, and make an assignment `lst[[All,1]] = 1`, say, then all first elements of sublists will be set to `1`. The construct I used generalizes that to the case when we set different sublists to different elements.

Comment: I think perhaps I see. Using `Part` forces the `Set`ting to happen element-wise. In addition, it seems that the dimensions mis-matching is important. What I mean is the difference between, say,
`lst[[All, 1]] = {1, 2, 3}` and `lst[[All, 1]] = {1, 2}` if `lst = {{a}, {b, c}}`.

Comment: @march Yes. You kind of interate over left-most `All`, while the right-most `All` works to say that all elements of a given sub-list should be given one and the same value.

Comment: I use that trick often in bit-mapping code. +1

Comment: @ciao Thanks. I wonder whether there is a trick you don't know :)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Lol - pretty much any time I read a neat answer by you, mw, mg, et, al., I pick up a new one and/or feel like a neophyte...

Comment: @ciao Well, quite frankly, from what I've seen from your posts, you are one of the finest experts on  performance-tuning we have on this site, and there is quite a bit for me to learn from you answers on this topic.

Comment: @Szabolcs Check out the modified version of the code - it covers also negative integers, as well as cases when there are large integers.

Answer (score 2):

```
fun[lst_, part_] := 
 Flatten[Last@Reap[MapIndexed[Sow[#2[[1]], #1] &, part], lst, #2 &]]
```

I make no comment re: efficiency and have upvoted Leonid Shifrin and am happy to delete if assessed as non-contributory.