# Which elements of a large array are part of a set?

Tags: performance-tuning, list-manipulation

I have a large integer packed array `arr`.  My array is multidimensional, but for simplicity let's consider 1D arrays for now.  `ArrayReshape` takes care of the rest.

I also have a `set` of integers (a list).

The task is to replace those elements of `arr` which are in `set` with 1, and those which aren't with 0.

What is the best way to do it, where "best" means fastest for as long we don't run out of memory?

For testing purposes, let's use

```
n = 100000000;
k = 20;
arr = RandomInteger[100, n];
set = RandomInteger[100, k];
```

---

What have I tried so far?

**Method 1.** For a single element of `set`, denoted `elem`, we can test using `1 - Unitize[arr - elem]`.  We can test for each element of `set` one by one using

```
res = 1 - Fold[# Unitize[arr - #2] &, ConstantArray[1, Length[arr]], set];
```

This is linear in the size of `set`, and we can do better than that.  I used `Fold` instead of mapping over `set` to avoid having to simultaneously store a huge array in memory for each element of `set`.

**Method 2.** An alternative is using associations for looking up the set elements, which should be no worse than logarithmic complexity in the size of `set` (i.e. much better than linear).

```
ass = AssociationThread[set -> ConstantArray[1, Length[set]]]
res = Lookup[ass, arr, 0];
```

It's clear that for large enough `k` this will be faster than method 1 due to its better complexity.  In practice the threshold where that happens is only $k=5$ for my test data.  But this method does not produce a packed array result, which is a disadvantage!

For comparison, I also implemented the same thing in C++ (using a naive lookup with `std::set`).  For $k=5$ I get the following timings: 5.9 s for method 1; 5.9 s for method 2 (re-packing the array takes an additional 0.7 s); 1.4 s for C++.

Comment: Since I already have a fast C++ version, which I could further speed up using OpenMP, this question is a bit theoretical.  But I would still like to know if I could have done better in pure Mathematica!

Comment: Something with `SparseArray`? Thinking out loud here...

Comment: With On["Packing"] I don't see an unpack message for method 2.

Comment: @M.R. I didn't phrase it correctly.  What I mean is that the result of `Lookup` is never a packed array, thus it will take up 3 times the storage than a packed version would.  I did not mean that the input to `Lookup` gets unpacked (in fact I didn't look at whether that happens).

Answer (score 13):

Here is a version that seems pretty fast and does not involve compiled code:

```
ClearAll[getMask];
getMask[arr_, set_] :=
  Module[{max = Max[arr], min = Min[arr], inds, dim, lset},
    lset = Pick[set, UnitStep[set - min]*UnitStep[max - set], 1];
    dim = max - min + 1;
    inds = SparseArray[{}, dim];
    inds[[lset - min + 1]] = 1;
    inds[[arr - min + 1]]
  ]
```

It uses the main idea similar to the one I used [in my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95413) to another question of yours. Basically, we create an index array, where your original data serve as indices.

It returns the result on a test data of the same sizes as in your question, in about 3 sec. on my machine. An added advantage is that the data is returned already in the `SparseArray` form, which in some cases may be a lot more memory-efficient.

In now deleted answer, [WReach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/142/wreach) used a similar method based on simple integer arrays. I didn't use it here intentionally, due to memory considerations, although it is slightly faster. However, it just occurred to me that since here there are no indications that the data is sparse, one can use that too, without much memory overhead, in general. You can look at my answer I linked above, where I used both and introduced automatic method switch based on the sparseness parameter. Something very similar can be done here, if needed.

Also, while I didn't do it, but one can optimize this further in cases when all integers are strictly positive.

Comment: Very interesting is to look on the timings with varying sizes of `set`. It seems that on my machine (8-core Intel i7), I [pretty much catch you](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDCmM.png) around `k>100`. Szabolcs method [beats you for small](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BvO5Q.png) `k`, but it gets very slow for larger values and it's in a different complexity class.

Comment: @halirutan Interesting... My own benchmark was showing that my code is 10x faster than Szabolcs's for `k=20`. I could not compare to yours, since I don't have a C compiler currently installed on my machine. I am on MacBook Pro Intel Core i7 (2 cores), 2.9 GHz, 8 Gb RAM.

Answer (score 6):

I tried to find a solution that uses the vectorization capabilities of `Compiled`, because in its core, this problem is very nice parallelizable. Unfortunately, I got only very inconsistent timings and it seems to be hard to know upfront why a certain implementation is faster or slower.

Let's assume we want to compute one element `i` from the array `arr`, then there are several ways to do this. One way is

```
1 - Min[Unitize[set - i]]
```

This code works similar to what Szabolcs is doing, but using `Min` instead of a multiplication seemed a bit faster. Another way to compute one element is a very simple loop that goes through all elements of `set` and returns 1 when it has found `i` in `set`.

```
Module[{res = 0},
 Do[
  If[i == j,
   res = 1;
   Break[];
   ], {j, set}
  ];
 res
 ]
```

Let's use these two bodies inside a compiled function:

```
fc1 = Compile[{{i, _Integer, 0}, {set, _Integer, 1}},
   Module[{res = 0},
    Do[
     If[i == j,
      res = 1;
      Break[];
      ], {j, set}
     ];
    res
    ],
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed",
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];

fc2 = Compile[{{i, _Integer, 0}, {set, _Integer, 1}},
   1 - Min[Unitize[set - i]],
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

Measuring the runtime against Szabolcs method using a 3d `arr` instead of a one dimensional list:

```
n = 500;
k = 20;
arr = RandomInteger[100, {n, n, n}];
set = RandomInteger[100, k];

res = 1 - Fold[# Unitize[arr - #2] &, 
  ConstantArray[1, Length[arr]], set]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

The calculation of `res` took **5.06 s** on my machine.

```
res2 = fc1[arr, set]; // AbsoluteTiming
res3 = fc2[arr, set]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

While the calculation of `res2` takes **5.46 s**, `res3` only uses **4.45 s** which is over half a second faster.

Before you ask, yes it was intentional to leave the `CompilationTarget` in `fc2` out. It's just faster that way on my machine. `fc1` on the other hand becomes even slower if it is not compiled to `"C"`.

**That's not the end of the story!** If I change `arr` now and use a simple one dimensional array of size 10^8 like Szabolcs did, then the timing is really weird.

Szabolcs' method needs 4.06 s, `fc1` now only needs 3.21 s and `fc2` needs a runtime of 4.64 s.

Maybe you like to try this yourself.